# display available objects in django form field if available and if not then create new

Tags: python, django, forms

i am trying to get all available objects in form field.

```
class A:
   name = charfield()
   age = charfield()

class B:
   classa = foriegnket(A)
   surname = charfield()
   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.surname

form a:
   class meta:
      model =A

form b:
   class meta:
      model =B
```

Now when i render this forms together and at the time of of filling surname it should automatically provide the available objects for b model. As user types in fields it should automatically suggest user the available objects of b class.
What is the best way to approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use django-autocomplete-light library.

Here's a documentation of autocomplete.

http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/

Comment: i want the same feature in django forms in templates.

Comment: You can use same feature in djnago forms also.
This is the ready made library which you can implement by reading docs. 
If you want to built your own, the rough idea is,  get all objects of B, in variable in views.py, and use them in html page using jquery autocomplete. If you find this solution, please, voteup